# Trying to save Vpn to Preferences on Mac (10.15.7) but getting: Domain=NEConfigurationErrorDomain Code=10 "permission denied"

Tags: swift, xcode, vpn

I am trying to connect to VPN on my Mac OS using Swift. I have setup the code, and it tries to save the VPN-data to the OS. But when running the code i get this in my console:

```
2020-11-16 12:26:56.306167+0100 VPN.test[53978:1477837] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-11-16 12:26:56.436101+0100 VPN.test[53978:1477890] []  Failed to save configuration Test VPN: Error Domain=NEConfigurationErrorDomain Code=10 "permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=permission denied}
2020-11-16 12:26:56.437294+0100 VPN.test[53978:1477837] [] Failed to save configuration: Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=5 "permission denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=permission denied}
Could not save VPN Configurations
```

The source code is here: https://codeshare.io/G7NWdn

I am fairly new to xCode / swift, so maybe there is something I miss. Have tried to look up solutions on the internet, but nothing seems to work.

Hope some can help me!

Comment: Probably not your fault (as in "something" happened), but voting to close because this is a complete duplicate of your question one minute ago (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64857302/trying-to-save-vpn-to-preferences-on-mac-10-15-7-but-getting-domain-neconfigu). You really need to delete one of these!

Comment: I deleted it sorry.

Comment: I havent found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding network extensions into Capabilities.